# Antd Column render async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Im trying to populate a column in a Antd table (that's not in the data) via the render property for columns through an async function named **func1** :

```
...
o.render = (text, record) => (<Progress percent = { func1.then((res)=> {return res} ) />)
...
```

The issue is instead of displaying the returned values from the async function, its shows `[object Promise]`.

How can i reprieve the correct value from the and display accurately?

Any pointers appreciated..

Comment: You passing a promise thats why it logs as an obj, you need to resolve it beforehand.

Comment: @DennisVash thank you how would i to that here please?

Comment: You can put the results in a state, resolve the `func1` in `useEffect` or whatever you using, and pass it.

Comment: @DennisVash not really possible as the func1 receive arguments specific to that row.. :(

Comment: All possible, you render a component, you can make a Row component and do it there.

Comment: @DennisVash ok, i will do some further research. Would be greatful if you can share an implementation.

Comment: There are enough questions on promises on SO, also, I don't know how your component looks like, how `func1` looks like, and where it comes from, so I can't. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash no worries, appreciate your help 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without any context, possible solution might look like so:

```
o.render = (text, record) => (
  <RowComp text={text} record={record} promise={func1} />
);

const RowComp = ({ promise, ...props }) => {
  useEffect(async () => {
    const res = await promise;
    setResult(res);
  }, []);
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks this model implementation is the way to go. I managed to get it working. Thank you